# Como desinstalar um pacote tar.bz2?

Tags: linux

Recentemente instalei o `ghdl` no meu Debian x64,
porém instalei a versão errada, feito isso desinstalei o `ghdl` e instalei a versão para x64 bits; porém o antigo `ghdl` (versão 0.29) continua no sistema, fiquei então com 2 compiladores `vhdl`. Quando faço o `apt-get remove`, ele só remove a versão que eu precisava usar.

#### Procedimento que usei para instalar o pacote

> ```
> By downloading the binaries and unpacking them manually:
>
>  $ wget http://ghdl.free.fr/site/uploads/Main/ghdl-i686-linux-latest.tar
>
>  $ sudo tar xvf ghdl-i686-linux-latest.tar
> ```
>
> (This generates the file ghdl-0.29-i686-pc-linux.tar.bz2)
>
> ```
>  $ cd ghdl-0.29-i686-pc-linux
>
>  $ sudo tar -C / -jxvf ghdl-0.29-i686-pc-linux.tar.bz2
> ```
>
> (This copy the files to /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib)
>
> Anyway, the destination directory should be already included in PATH.

**Fonte**: [UMHDL Manual](https://sourceforge.net/projects/umhdl/files/)

Eu segui essa instrução para instalar o pacote errado, agora não sei como faço pra desinstalar, como proceder?

Answer (score 3):

Conforme dito nas instruções, os arquivos foram copiados para os diretórios `/usr/local/bin` e `/usr/local/lib`. Só para constar, distribuições como o Debian possuem uma diferenciação por padrão: pacotes instalados manualmente vão para `/usr/local`, enquanto pacotes nativos da distribuição (instalados com `apt-get`, por exemplo) vão para `/usr`. Você disse que `apt-get remove` remove sua versão desejada, então é de se supor que ela tenha sido instalada com `apt-get install`.

Se você realmente quer remover os indesejados, então, pela estrutura do seu pacote, esses comandos devem resolver:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo rm -f ghdl
cd /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4
sudo rm -rf vhdl
```